# How to derive pmf from a ramdom variable X to a random variable Y = (-1)^X?

Tags: calculus, statistics

Assume the random variable X has distribution X ∼ Bin(9, 0.5) and let 
Y = (−1)^X. 
Derive the probability mass function of Y .
I know how to derive the mean and variance, but how to derive the pmf? Can anyone helps me out?

Comment: **Hint:** Try to condition on values $X$ can take.

Comment: i.e. Look up the law of total probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X \sim Binom(9, .5),$ then by symmetry, $P(X \text{ even}) = 0.5.$
[Note that ${a+b \choose a} = {a+b \choose b},$ for non-negative integers $a$ and $b.$]

So $P((-1)^X = 1) = 0.5.$ You can finish it from there.

```
# Using R statistical software:
sum(dbinom(c(0,2,4,6,8), 9, .5))
## 0.5
```

[image]