# PMF of function of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, self-learning

**Let X be  a Geom($\frac{1}{2}$) random variable, and define Y=$X^{-1}$**

**What is the p.m.f. of Y ?**

*attempt:*

pmf of a Geom RV in general form is $p(1-p)^{k-1}$

There is [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2119282/how-to-derive-pmf-from-a-ramdom-variable-x-to-a-random-variable-y-1x), not for the same type of RV, but it doesn't actually explain, the accepted answer states "You can finish it from there"

I've also [watched this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qx2NKaUCUw0), but in the example the range of values is explicitly defined.

I'm not sure how to relate the p.m.f of X to p.m.f of Y for this specific case of mine

Comment: Here, the range of values is not explicitly defined, but you can deduce that it is $\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$, because that is what is support of a geometric random variable is. Then apply the same method in the video, the only difference being that the underlying set is infinite.

Comment: to the person down voted; why the down vote? you can't just down vote and not explain what is wrong. There are already answers on the question.

Answer (score 3):

$X$ takes positive integer valyes and $Y$ takes the values $1,\frac 1 2,\frac 1 3,...$. We have $P(Y=\frac 1 n)=P(X=n)=p(1-p)^{n-1}$.

Comment: where are you getting those values? This answer does not not answer my question. Nor does it provide sufficient explanation. No source. why is this up voted?

Comment: If $x \in \mathbb N$ the $\frac 1 x \in \{1,\frac 1 2,\frac 1 3,...\}$ right?

Comment: Your answer states it takes values 1, 1/2,1/2  ??

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Since $X$ is concentrated on the positive integers, $Y=1/X$ is concentrated on the set $S=\{1/k\colon\, k\geq 1\}$  i.e. $P(Y\in S)=1$. Hence it sufficies to compute the probability mass function of $Y$ for points in $S$. But
$$
P(Y=k^{-1})=P(X=k)=2^{-k}
$$
for $k=1,2,3, \dotsc$ as desired.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the answer please? and why is it so different than the answer Kavi Rama Murthy has given?

Comment: It is exactly the same answer. Just take p=1/2

Comment: that'll give (1/2)*(1/2)^(n-1) ?? asking again: could you show the steps in your answer?

Comment: Which simplified gives $2^{-n}$. The same as my answer no?